# TD Heights and explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I know this has been asked a million times and I've tried all the solutions I've found on here but nothing.

This is my page: http://www.osteriaalcason.it and as you can see if you open it with Internet Explorer all the menu is spaced out completely wrong. Instead with Firefox or Chrome the menu is correctly visualized.

You should be able to see the source of the page directly from your browser and the CSS file is here:
http://www.osteriaalcason.it/rist.css
where you can see my latest attempts:

```
.menu {
width:150px;
height:30px;
max-height:30px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size:1px;
}

.menu A:link{
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu A:visited{
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu A:active{
text-decoration:none;
}

 .menu A:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}

 .menu img{
max-height:30px;
border-style: none;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: If you struggle, you could try giving a fixed height to the columns and set `overflow:hidden` style on the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have change some html and it's working fine in IE also. 
You can check below jsfiddle.
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pqt2Q/)

Comment: Hi, you've changed the two coloumns into 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: Hi this doesn't change anything